# Proving a metric space to be separable if every infinite set in the metric space has a limit point in it.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

**Let $X$ be a metric space such that every infinite set in it has a limit point. I want to prove that $X$ is separable that is $X$ has a countable dense subset.** 
$X$ may either be countable or uncountable. 
If $X$ is countable then since $cl (X)=X$, it follows that $X$ is countable base of itself and hence $X$ is separable.

If $X$ is uncountable then let's try to prove contrapositive like this: 
Suppose that $X$ is not separable, it follows that for every countable subset $A\subset X, \exists $ an open set $U_A$ in $X$ such that $U_A\cap X=\emptyset$. Here onwards I don't know **how to construct a countable set in $X$ which does not have any limit point.**

I tried to construct one countably infinite set $(x_n)\subset X $whose all elements are separated from each other by at least a
fixed distance  say $d\gt 0$ but didn't get any countable set. I chose $x_1\in X$ and $x_2\in X\setminus \{x_1\}$ so that $d(x_1,x_2)\ge \delta$ but the problem is what if for all $x\in X$, we have $d(x_1,x)\lt \delta$.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think the title of the post would be better if the term "infinite series" were replaced by "infinite sequence".  While the term "series" sometimes is used to mean the same thing as "sequence", I don't advise using it with the label "infinite" in that meaning because the phrase "infinite series" is overwhelmingly understood to mean a sum of infinitely many terms, not a sequence of infinitely many terms.

Comment: @KCd: Edited. That was erroneously put there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove this lemma: given any $\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon} \newcommand{\ma}{\mathbb} \newcommand{\nf}{\infty} \newcommand{\fa}{\;\forall\;}\eps>0$, there exists some finite collection of points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in X$ such that the finite collection of open balls $\{B(x_i;\eps)\}_{i=1}^n$ covers $X$. To prove this, we show the contrapositive. We suppose this is not the case, and then show that $X$ has an infinite set with no limit point (this property is called limit point compactness, by the way).

Letting $y_1$ be any point of $X$, $B(y_1;\eps)$ cannot cover $X$ (because otherwise $\{B(y_1;\eps)\}$ would be our desired finite open covering). Now suppose we are given points $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m$ such that the collection $\{B(y_i;\eps)\}_{i=1}^m$ does not cover $X$. We then set $y_{m+1}$ equal to any point of the nonempty set $X-\cup_{i=1}^m B(y_i;\eps)$. In this way, we have constructed an infinite sequence of points, $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{\nf}$, such that for any integer $n\in\ma Z^+$, the collection $\{B(y_i;\eps)\}_{i=1}^n$ does not cover $X$. Because of the way we constructed this sequence of $y_i$s, it is clear that for any $j>k$, $y_j$ does not belong to $B(y_k;\eps)$, so $d(y_j,y_k)\geq \eps$. Interchanging the roles of $j$ and $k$, we get that $d(y_j,y_k)\geq \eps, \fa j\neq k$. We now have everything we need to demonstrate a contradiction. I claim that $A=\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{\nf}$ is an infinite set with no limit point. because $d(y_j,y_k)\geq\eps, \fa j\neq k$, $y_j\neq y_k, \fa j\neq k$, so all $y_i$s are distinct, making $A$ infinite. To show that $A$ has no limit point, suppose to the contrary that it does. Call this limit point $z$. As $z$ is a limit point of $A$ and $X$ (being a metric space) is $T_1$, the neighborhood $B(z;\frac{\eps}{2})$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. This means, in particular, that we choose distinct integers, $p$ and $q$, such that $y_p$ and $y_q$ both belong to $B(z;\frac{\eps}{2})$. But this means $d(y_p,y_q)\leq d(y_p,z)+d(z,y_q)<\frac{\eps}{2}+\frac{\eps}{2}=\eps$, a contradiction. It follows that $A$ has no limit point.

Taking the contrapositive of what was just proved, we get the statement of the first paragraph (assuming $X$ is a limit point compact metric space). Now for each positive integer, $n$, let $\{x_{i,n}\}_{i=1}^{m_n}$ be a finite collection of points in $X$ such that $\{B(x_{i,n};\frac{1}{n})\}_{i=1}^{m_n}$ covers $X$. The collection of points $\{x_{i,n}\}_{1\leq i\leq m_n, 1\leq n\leq \nf}$ is clearly countable. I now leave it to you to show that this collection is also dense in $X$.

(a fact that is relevant and interesting here is that the kinds of metric spaces your question is about are exactly the compact metric spaces)

Comment: Very nice :) Thanks a lot for your answer :). Sure, I'll try to prove the dense nature of the infinite set  like this: If $x\in X\setminus S$, then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0\exists \frac 1{n_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon$ such that $B(x,\frac 1{n_\epsilon})\subset B(x,\epsilon)$ and $x\in B(x_{i,n_\epsilon},\frac 1{n_\epsilon})$ for some $i\in \{1,2,\cdots, m_{n_\epsilon}\}$ and hence $d(x,x_{i,n_\epsilon})\lt \frac 1{n_\epsilon}\implies x_{i, n_{\epsilon}}\in B(x,\epsilon)$$ \implies$ every open ball in $X$ contains an element of the infinite set and hence the set is dense. :) +1

Comment: @Koro Yes, you're absolutely correct.